# Creating multiple txt files from a text file

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, text, txt

I am trying to take the Federalist Papers from Project Gutenberg and convert them into text documents. The issue with Project Gutenberg is that each paper is not separated out - it reads in as one large text file, so I have to tell Python to create a new text file for each Federalist Paper (they are each contained between the phrase `"FEDERALIST No. _"` and `"PUBLIUS"`).

The code that I have works mostly, but the issue I'm running into is with the first text file it creates (named `1.txt`, per my code). When I open this file, it contains the entire original text scraped from Project Gutenberg, not just the text for Federalist 1. The file `2.txt` then has the contents only for Federalist 1, which is correctly cutting the text, it's just now offset from the file that it is supposed to be by 1.

I suspect my issue is somewhere in the `for`-loop, and maybe with how I'm initializing my variables, but I can't see where it's causing this error.

```
# Importing the doc and creating individual txt files for each federalist paper

url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1404/1404.txt"
response = request.urlopen(url)
raw = response.read().decode('utf8')

# finding the start and end of the portion of the doc we care about and subsetting
raw.find("FEDERALIST No. 1")
raw.rfind("PUBLIUS")
raw = raw[821:1167459]
# fixing the doc again... yeah this ain't clean but it's right
raw = raw[0:1166638]
# save as txt to work with below
print(raw, file=open("all.txt", "a"))

# looping over the whole text to break it into individual text docs by each
# federalist paper
with open("all.txt") as fo:
    op = ''
    start = 0
    cntr = 1
    paper = 1
    for x in fo.read().split("\n"):  # looping over the text by each line split
        if x == 'FEDERALIST No. ' + str(paper):  # creating new txt if we
                                                 # encounter a new fed paper
            if start == 1:
                with open(str(cntr) + '.txt', 'w') as opf:
                    opf.write(op)
                    opf.close()
                    op = ''
                    cntr += 1
                    paper += 1
            else:
                start = 1
        else:
            if op == '':
                op = x
            else:
                op = op + '\n' + x
    fo.close()
```

Comment: if You use `with` to open file then there is no need for `.close` as it will happen automatically when exiting the statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re` module to *split* the text:

```py
import re
import requests


url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1404/1404.txt"
text = requests.get(url).text

r = re.compile(
    r"^(FEDERALIST No\..*?)(?=^PUBLIUS|^FEDERALIST)", flags=re.M | re.S
)
for i, section in enumerate(r.findall(text), 1):
    with open("{}.txt".format(i), "w") as f_out:
        f_out.write(section)
```

This will create 85 `.txt` files each containing section from the paper.